# How to update a couchdb document with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchdb

I have a Rails application with MYSQL backend. Upon saving data in MYSQL, it pushes some data to Couchdb using curl commands. However, I am unable to update that very same document. I dont know how query from couchdb and use _rev id to update. Here is how am creating and pushing a couchdb document.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

def push_to_couchdb
 url = URI.parse("http://127.0.0.1:5984/m5fcash/100")
 request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(url)
 request.body = JSON.dump({
    "fname" => "fname",
    "lanme" => "lname",
    "type"  => "demo",
    "facility"  => "spectre"
})
req_options = {
    use_ssl: url.scheme == "https",
}
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.hostname, url.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
end
```

This is how am trying to query the document and extract its _rev id

```
def get_couch_doc
 uri = URI.parse("http://127.0.0.1:5984/m5fcash/100")
 response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)     
 raise response.inspect
end
```

I expect *raise response.inspect* to gove a couchdb document from which I will exctract a _rev id. But all I get is *#.* How can I query a document in Ruby using curl??

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me from your code what you're trying to do, so I'll try to explain in general terms.

In order to read a specific document revsion, you need to use the `rev=...` query parameter. This is probably not what you want. In your `get_couch_doc` you can't have a request body. It looks like you're trying to fetch a document based on specific data in the body -- for this you need to create a secondary index, known as a view in CouchDB.

If you want to be able to query based on the `lanme` (maybe that should be `lname`?) field, you'd make a view where the map could look something like

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.lname) {
    emit(doc.lname, null);
  }
}
```

If you want to *update* a document, you need to do a `PUT database/doc_id` with the `rev=....` query parameter on the URL.

CouchDB [docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/document/common.html) for the document API, and for [views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/index.html).

Comment: I have refactored my code. I am using Ruby on Rails to create and update couchdb documents.

Comment: If you rewite your question fundamentally, answers already given become much harder to read :). My advice would be to put Ruby aside for a bit, and get your CouchDB APIi queries working with curl first, from the command-line. In general, doing a PUT to create a new doc, will return the revision id in the response.